# Get the value with Memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I'm trying to figure out how to use memcached, I'm successful getting the entire row but can't figure out how to choose a specific result.

This is what I have:

```
 $mylink = new LTR_Links();
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->connect("localhost",11211); 
$mylink->Link = $_GET['redirect'];
$res = $memcache->get($mylink->Link);
var_dump($res);
```

Here I get the out out which looks like this:

```
object(LTR_Links)#4 (7) { ["sResult":protected]=> int(0) ["sQuery":protected]=> string(23) "select * from LTR_Links" ["sTemplate":protected]=> NULL ["sTemplateCache":protected]=> NULL ["ID"]=> string(3) "123" ["Destination"]=> string(8) "44444444" ["hasFile"]=> bool(false) }
```

But how do I get to the

> Destination

If I give a key the script dies. Like:

```
echo $res['Destination'];
```

So how on earth do I get the value??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.
I didn't do set correctly.